# What is the local/global problem with R?

Tags: r, programming-languages

Under what circumstances does the following example return a local x versus a global x?

The xi'an blog wrote the following at http://xianblog.wordpress.com/2010/09/13/simply-start-over-and-build-something-better/

One of the worst problems is scoping. Consider the following little gem.

```
f =function() {
if (runif(1) > .5)
x = 10
x
}
```

The x being returned by this function is randomly local or global. There are other examples where variables alternate between local and non-local throughout the body of a function. No sensible language would allow this. It’s ugly and it makes optimisation really difficult. This isn’t the only problem, even weirder things happen  because of interactions between scoping and lazy evaluation.

PS - Is this xi'an blog post written by Ross Ihaka?

Edit - Follow up question.

Is this the remedy?

```
f = function() {
  x = NA
  if (runif(1) > .5)
    x = 10
  x
}
```

Comment: That post wasn't written by Ross, Xi'an's Og reproduced some/all of a comment Ross made to the posting on Xi'an's Og linked to in the first line of the posting. You have copied verbatim something the Xi'an's Og copied verbatim from Ross's comment.

Comment: As @GavinSimpson points out in his very good answer, this is not a problem with R. Every other programming language I have ever worked with has some kind of mechanism that does the same thing, i.e. allowing local variable as well as global variables.  So you should be able to replicate this little example in many other languages too.  R is relaxed about forcing you to declare the type of variable, but this doesn't mean you shouldn't...

Comment: Is this some sort of over the top "re-tweeting" exercise? I'm confused...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'x' is only declared in the function if the 'if' condition is true, so if 'runif(1)>.5' then the second mentioning of the x will make the function return your local x (10), otherwise it will return a globally defined 'x' (and if 'x' is not defined globally then it will fail)

```
    > f =function() {
    + if (T)
    + x = 10
    + x
    + }
    > f()
    [1] 10

    > f =function() {
    + if (F)
    + x = 10
    + x
    + }
    > f()
    Error in f() : Object 'x' not found

    > x<-77
    > f()
    [1] 77
```

Comment: So you could first declare x = NA in the function...  Is there a generally accepted procedure for this?

Comment: @Jeff - No, that is not bad. It is only bad if you write poor R code. Scoping can be useful if you know what you are doing and want to exploit features of the language. It can also bite you in the ass if you don't understand those features of the language.

Comment: Seems bad to me. Since the majority of R users aren't programmers, ideally the language would protect you from hurting yourself.

Comment: I'm not a programmer. I'm also not an expert marksman; if handed a gun, I shouldn't be surprised if I shoot myself in the foot once in a while until I learn how to use the gun. I think you are reading too much into Ross's example. It was intended to be simple and silly to highlight the problem.s you can get into. But there is no-one advocating that you *should* write R code that way - certainly not Ross. This is not to say R can't be improved, and maybe the improvement might not have this scoping feature, but R is a language and you need to learn how to use it.

Comment: You can use this to define a global default and conditional local override. You know that if you always want the local x just define 'x<-something' before the 'if'. The syntactic choice in R prevents functions to (e.g. accidentally) change globals (the global x was not changed by 'x=10'). Personally, I prefer an explicit declaration inside functions, then the language can decide which 'x' to choose depending on where the closest declaration was.

Comment: @Jeff - My understanding was that Ross's example was meant to illustrate cases that make *optimizing R's underlying performance* challenging, not that this sort of scoping behavior is necessarily bad in and of itself. Namely, that this sort of ambiguous scoping/lazy evaluation behavior makes optimizing the underlying C/FORTRAN code for speed very difficult.

Answer (score 6):

This is only a problem if you write functions that do not take arguments or the functionality relies on the scoping of variables outside the current frame. you either i) pass in objects you need in the function as arguments to that function, or ii) create those objects inside the function that uses them.

Your `f` is coded incorrectly. If you possibly alter `x`, then you should pass `x` in, possibly setting a default of `NA` or similar if that is what you want the other side of the random flip to be.

```
f <- function(x = NA) {
    if (runif(1) > .5)
    x <- 10
    x
}
```

Here we see the function works as per your second function, but by properly assigning `x` as an argument with appropriate default. Note this works even if we have another `x` defined in the global workspace:

```
> set.seed(3)
> replicate(10, f())
 [1] NA 10 NA NA 10 10 NA NA 10 10
> x <- 4
> set.seed(3)
> replicate(10, f())
 [1] NA 10 NA NA 10 10 NA NA 10 10
```

Another benefit of this is that you can pass in an `x` if you want to return some other value instead of `NA`. If you don't need that facility, then defining `x <- NA` *in* the function is sufficient.

The above is predicated on what you actually want to do with `f`, which isn't clear from your posting and comments. If all you want to do is randomly return `10` or `NA`, define `x <- NA`.

Of course, this function is very silly as it can't exploit vectorisation in R - it is very much a scalar operation, which we know is slow in R. A better function might be

```
f <- function(n = 1, repl = 10) {
    out <- rep(NA, n)
    out[runif(n) > 0.5] <- repl
    out
}
```

or

```
f <- function(x, repl = 10) {
    n <- length(x)
    out <- rep(NA, n)
    out[runif(n) > 0.5] <- repl
    out
}
```

Ross's example function was, I surmise, intentionally simple and silly to highlight the scoping issue - it should not be taken as an example of writing good R code, nor would it have been intended as such. Be aware of the scoping feature and code accordingly, and you won't get bitten. You might even find you can exploit this feature...